# paypal error token not received

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal payments pro express checkout. I've used the following code:

https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-getexpresscheckoutdetails-php-5.3/nvp

I entered my Api credentials and also turned on the relevant website preferences, but I keep getting the error, token is not received. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'm lost.

Comment: I should also add that I tried the SOAP version and could not get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments of that script:

```
/**
 * This example assumes that this is the return URL in the SetExpressCheckout API call.
 * The PayPal website redirects the user to this page with a token.
 */
```

From what I understand, you need to direct the user to PayPal first, and send the return_url to point to this script. Then after the user has paid, he will be redirected to this script.

Comment: I'll look into it. I thought the purpose of PayPal Payments Pro was to not have them leave your website ever.